# Android layout xml rotation orientation

Tags: java, android, xml, cordova, layout

I am converting the starter Android sample Camera2Video example: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Video

When running the example by itself the rotation works well, and the controls are always visible. However when I embed the same code inside a Cordova plugin, the controls dissapear when rotated.

Here is the layout xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.example.android.camera2video.AutoFitTextureView
        android:id="@+id/texture"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/texture"
        android:background="#4285f4">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/video"
            style="@android:style/Widget.Material.Light.Button.Borderless"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:contentDescription="Record"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/record" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/info"
            android:contentDescription="Info"
            style="@android:style/Widget.Material.Light.Button.Borderless"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/gallery" />

    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is the layout-land xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.example.android.camera2video.AutoFitTextureView
        android:id="@+id/texture"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/texture"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/texture"
        android:background="#4285f4"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/video"
            style="@android:style/Widget.Material.Light.Button.Borderless"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:contentDescription="Record"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/record" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/info"
            style="@android:style/Widget.Material.Light.Button.Borderless"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
            android:contentDescription="Info"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/gallery" />

    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Also there is code to detect the rotation.

I'm sure it's a simple fix, I just can't figure it out!

My full plugin code: https://github.com/kmturley/cordova-plugin-media-custom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this using the following code:

layout xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextureView
        android:id="@+id/texture"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#66000000"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/video"
            style="@android:style/Widget.Material.Light.Button.Borderless"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:contentDescription="Record"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/record"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/info"
            android:contentDescription="Info"
            style="@android:style/Widget.Material.Light.Button.Borderless"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/gallery"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />

    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

layout landscape xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextureView
        android:id="@+id/texture"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="#66000000"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/video"
            style="@android:style/Widget.Material.Light.Button.Borderless"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:contentDescription="Record"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/record"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/info"
            android:contentDescription="Info"
            style="@android:style/Widget.Material.Light.Button.Borderless"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/gallery"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />

    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

You can see it working on my cordova plugin here:

https://github.com/kmturley/cordova-plugin-media-custom